# C# : how to register / associate my app with a file type for XP *and* Vista?

Tags: c#, file, windows-vista, associations

What's the simplest way to associate my application with a file-extension that works for both Vista and previous versions of Windows ?

Does anyone have an example ?

Comment: The keyword here is "for Vista AND previous versions of Windows".

Comment: I believe that the other thread does tell you about Vista, as it says that there will be problems if the users UAC privilege isn't high enough.

Comment: The whole idea of filetype-associations is different in Vista, as Vista is using it's "default applications" setup per user.
As I understood (but I might be wrong) hacking the registry is therefore not recommended.
I'm just wondering if the old registry-hacks are not recommended, what the correct approach would be.

Answer (score 2):

This answer won't work for everyone - but if you are deploying a ClickOnce application (it's worth considering, at least) then you can set file-associations in **Visual Studio** for your app.

In the ClickOnce application Properties (this is for VS 2008):

- **Publish** tab
- Install Mode and Settings --> The application is available offline as well
- **Options...** button
- Publish Options --> File Assocations
- Set up the Extension|Description|ProgID|Icon that you wish to trigger your app

I tried it with this 'beta' app [DeepZoomViewer](http://www.deepzoompublisher.com/Viewer/) ([ClickOnce published](http://www.deepzoompublisher.com/Viewer/publish.htm)) - the file associations (in this case .DZI and .DZC) definitely work on both XP and Vista.

Even better, when you *uninstall* the ClickOnce app, the file associations it created are *removed* for you (again, my test app uses .DZI and .DZC). No registry hacking required.

EDIT: another link describing [manually adding the file associations](http://blogs.msdn.com/mwade/archive/2008/01/30/how-to-add-file-associations-to-a-clickonce-application.aspx).

Comment: From the MSDN site :
"To Set the ClickOnce Deployment Properties You must have a completed Windows Application that uses Crystal Reports"

This is going a bit too far for me - just because I want to assiociate a file type I have to use a special installer which in turn forces me to use Crystal Reports even though I really don't need it..

Comment: I can promise you the sample I linked to doesn't use Crystal Reports (in fact I don't have Crystal installed at all). If you click the publish.htm link in my answer, it will install the DeepZoomViewer and file-associations - but definitely no Crystal Reports!

If you are referring to this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227326.aspx
it is part of the Crystal Reports documentation (!) which is why it mentions Crystal Reports. Sometimes Google doesn't give you "exactly" the right page...

Comment: Ah, in that case I'll have another look, thanks !!

Still I'm leaving this open as I think there should be a normal way (without ClickOnce) to register filetype associations from C# code in the OS, be it XP or Vista....